# Range in Python 3x

Tags: python-3.x

in python 3x ,  when the user inputs a number i want the program to print him something like your number is in range. for example : if num = range(5,10) then print your number is in range ( if the number he gives is 7 )

```
int(input("Give a number from 1 to 20" ))
if num = range(2,5):
 print("your number is in range ")
else :
  print("your number is not in range")
```

Comment: why don't you just do a `if 2 <= num and num <= 5`, its more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the in expression.

```
2 in range(3, 100)
>>> False

3 in range(3, 100)
>>> True
```

So you can write:

```
if num in range(100, 200):
    print ("Your number is in range")
```